# Nivo Controlnav position

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider, nivo-slider

I'm using the Nivo Slider and I want to move the bullets (the controlnav) from the bottom of the slider to the top. I've tried for a while but jquery isn't really my strong side. The way it is now, it's position is changing when I resize the window. Is there a way to make it stick, or maybe get the div on top instead of under the slider?

Here is the code:

```
<div class="slider-wrapper">
    <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
        <img src="img/bird1.jpg" alt="" />
        <img src="img/bird2.jpg" alt="" />
        <img src="img/bird3.jpg" alt=""  />
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the controlnav in the nivo-slider css:

```
.nivo-controlNav {
position:fixed;
left:50%;
bottom:51%;
}

.nivo-controlNav a {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 99;
    float:left;
    }

.nivo-controlNav a.active {
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

And here is the controlnav javascript:

```
if(settings.controlNav){
        vars.controlNavEl = $('<div class="nivo-controlNav"></div>');
        slider.after(vars.controlNavEl);
        for(var i = 0; i < kids.length; i++){
            if(settings.controlNavThumbs){
                vars.controlNavEl.addClass('nivo-thumbs-enabled');
                var child = kids.eq(i);
                if(!child.is('img')){
                    child = child.find('img:first');
                }
                if(child.attr('data-thumb')) vars.controlNavEl.append('<a class="nivo-control" rel="'+ i +'"><img src="'+ child.attr('data-thumb') +'" alt="" /></a>');
            } else {
                vars.controlNavEl.append('<a class="nivo-control" rel="'+ i +'">'+ (i + 1) +'</a>');
            }
        }
```

I hope I explained it well enough, I would really appreaciate some help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can change where is says .after to .append, this will make the slider put the controlNav within the slider div.

However, beyond this I can't work out the height issues caused by doing this, without actually defining the height of the slider (I can't do this as I need it to be responsive to the window size). Any further help would be great.